# How to integrate google docs editor in website?

Tags: google-docs-api

I want to integrate google docs editor in my website. Is there a way to embed whole google docs editor under my web url

e.g www.example.com/docs.google.com/document...

I have read about `realtime API` and `drive API` but I am unsure that what I want is possible with this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this feature is not supported yet.